# Changes to Website Files Not Showing Up in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have migrated 2 DLLs and an aspx page to an existing web application on a production server. The changes in the file do not show up when I run the web application.

I have restarted the web application, restarted the associated application pool, run iisreset, deleted the Temporary ASP.NET Files. The changes do not show.

I have created a new html file in the root of the application, but it returns a 404 File Not Found error.

In IIS, I right-click the web application and choose Explore just to make sure that I am in the correct directory. I am. I see my updated files there. I can view the text of the aspx page, and my changes are there. My test html file is there.

I have searched StackOverflow, implementing all of the prior solutions I have seen that have fixed other poster's questions. Is there anything else I can do to IIS, the file system, or anything else to get these changes to show?

Comment: do you have recompiler your web application project after you migrated 2 Dlls?

Comment: I have tested the application in my Dev environment, and the changes are there.

Comment: I just need to get those changes to show up in the Production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not hitting the website that you think you are. Check your bindings and host headers, maybe another site on the server is intercepting the request.